# QT: Scroll widget that renders directly to the DC

Tags: windows, qt, gdi

I'm trying to create a widget which paints directly to the windows Device Context by calling `getDC()` and painting an `HBITMAP` to it.
The widget I'm painting resides inside a scroll widget.
I've implemented the `paintEvent()` and it does seem to paint but immediatly after painting the widget gets painted over again with a blank gray color.

I've tried setting `WA_PaintOnScreen` and `Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground` but none of those help.
In theory this should be possible since this is basically how the `GLWidget` works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here:

http://www.qtchina.net/qt4c++guiprogramming/ch20lev1sec1.html/

```
void GdiControl::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(winId(), &rect);
    HDC hdc = GetDC(winId());
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
    SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_CENTER | TA_BASELINE);
    TextOutW(hdc, width() / 2, height() / 2, text.utf16(), text.size());
    ReleaseDC(winId(), hdc);
}
```

> For this to work, we must also
>   reimplement
>   `QPaintDevice::paintEngine()` to return
>   a null pointer and set the
>   `Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen` attribute in the
>   widget's constructor.